# How to change C# AWS client Lambda invoke request timeout

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, lambda

How do I change the client side lambda invoke request timeout?
It seems that if Lambda invocation takes more than a minute and a half the following exception is thrown.
I'm using the .Net AmazonLambdaClient client.

```
ex=System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled. 
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport 
connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread 
exit or an application request. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The 
I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an 
application request
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the timeout when you create the `AmazonLambdaClient`.

```
var client = new AmazonLambdaClient(
  new AmazonLambdaConfig
  {
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000)            // Default value is 100 seconds
    //all other config values here
  });
```

See the [docs for `AmazonLambdaConfig`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Lambda/TLambdaConfig.html).

You might also see if you can replace your calls with `InvokeAsync` if you don't need to wait for them to return.